# How to make a latex document in landscape?

Tags: landscape

I have seen several posts related to this one, but I'm not satisfied with given explainations and examples. I can't get them working!

What I want is simple landscape document. I have tried the `\usepackage{pdflscape}` but only the paper rotates not the whole thing. The coordinates(0,0) are still at the upper right. I want the origin(0,0) at the upper left just like what happens when I do MS Word Landscape layout.

I really need your help.
I'm using Latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=13.0in,margin=0.1in,headheight=0.0in,footskip=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
%%\special{papersize=279mm,216mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{.SELECT UPPER(company_name) as c_comp,address as c_add,tel_nos as c_tel FROM tools.`clients` WHERE client_id=1}
\begin{textblock}{14}(0.75,0.08)
\raggedright{
\includegraphics[height=1.0in]{/u2/images/school/stc_logo}
}
\end{textblock}
\begin{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}` or use `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}`

Comment: then how to use the `\begin{landscape}`? Should I put my `\begin{document}` inside?

Comment: That is used inside a document for change orientation of a specific part if you want a portait layour. For this, you need package `pdflscape`.

Comment: remove the option `absolute` from `textpos`. See the answer below.

Answer (score 82):

You can create a landscape document by using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
```

or with the help of `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
```

Here text will be in landscape, but page directions will be the same. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at ($(current page.north east) + (-1cm,-1cm)$) {NE};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `NE` is the north east of the page while text is in `landscape`. On the other hand if you want only few pages in landscape, you can use `lscape` or `pdflscape` packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
%\usepackage{pdflscape} %uncomment this  and comment above line to see the difference
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
      \kant[1-4]
    \end{landscape}
    \kant[5-10]
\end{document}
```

`pdflscape` will auto rotate the page on the screen so as to make reading easy.

Having said that, in your example, remove the option `absolute` from `textpos`. Hence you will be able to keep the origin changing when you rotate the text. Further, you have used `_` in text which should be `\_`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=13.0in,margin=0.1in,headheight=0.0in,footskip=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
{.SELECT UPPER(company\_name) as c\_comp,address as c\_add,tel\_nos as c\_tel FROM tools.`clients` WHERE client\_id=1}
\begin{textblock}{14}((0.75,0.08))
\raggedright{
\includegraphics[height=1.0in]{example-image-a}
}
\end{textblock}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The MySQL query is not supposed to be printed, it's not part of the document itself but it does fetch data to be printed (QCGI syntax). But anyways, your example has given me an idea. Thanks.

Comment: For the case `\documentclass[landscape]{article}` and `pdflatex`, use `\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}` and `\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}` in preamble. Without it the `pdflatex` will produce portrait and you may waste a lot of time looking for the bug.

Comment: @dmitry_romanov That is why, we use `geometry` :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have some landscape pages in a portrait document, I recommend the `lscape` package.

It works like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}    
\begin{document}    
portrait    
\begin{landscape}
landscape
\end{landscape}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the second half of the existing answer.